# Disable "zoom in" function for google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I list my users on the google maps based on their locations.
But I dont want it zoom in to a degree where others can see on what street they live.
Is there a way to disable "zoom in" feature in the following Google maps codes?

Thanks!

```js
function initialize() {
    var data = <%=Data%>;
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(48.404840395764175, 2.6845264434814453);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
        var location = data.users[i];
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latLng });
        markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `minZoom` and `maxZoom` properties to the [options object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) you pass to the `Map` constructor:

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    maxZoom: 10
});
```

From the docs for `maxZoom`:

> The maximum zoom level which will be displayed on the map. If omitted,
>   or set to null, the maximum zoom from the current map type is used
>   instead.

Answer (score 2):

This can be used to disable scroll when mouse is hovered over map.

```
scrollwheel: false
```